# Spring security: Why use http-basic and form-login together?

Tags: spring, spring-security, basic-authentication

When using Spring Security how does this code work - specifically why is the basic authentication used together with form login, aren't they mutually exclusive ? In what situation does it make sense to use both of them like in the sample code below:

```
<http>
  <intercept-url pattern='/login.jsp' access='permitAll' />
  <intercept-url pattern='/**' access='ROLE_USER' />
    <http-basic />
    <form-login login-page='/login.jsp' always-use-default-target='true' />
</http>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you can use them separately.
But using them together allows us to secure Rest services using Basic Auth and 
Web Pages using form login.